# Grunt: how do I write a list of js files to a template for prod/dev environments

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I would like to know how I can define a list of js files in one place (preferably within gruntfile.js or external json file) and have it written to a template (alternating between dev and prod environments).

JS file list definition

```
var jsFiles = [
  'js/one.js',
  'js/two.js'
];
```

Template (this is how I would like it to work)

```
if(isProd) {
    print('<script type="text/javascript" src="js/combined.js"></script>\n');
} else {
    for(var i = 0, len = jsFiles.length; i < len; i++) {
        print('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + jsFiles[i] + '"></script>\n');
    }
}
```

Template Result (development)

```
<script src="js/one.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/two.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Template Result (production)

```
<script src="js/combined.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: for production, it sounds like you will want to add an additional task, to concat all your files.  at that point, it would be trivial to then add another task to uglify/minify your code too.  These are already available grunt-contrib tasks, I believe.

Comment: minifying output isn't the problem but reading and writing the template based on prod/dev tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`config`](https://npmjs.org/package/config) module to define a list of resources for both `development` and `production` environments: same property, but defined in different files, `config/development.js` and `config/production.js`.

The `config` module will automatically load the correct file for the current environment:

```
// config/development.js
module.exports = {
  jsFiles : [ 'js/one.js', 'js/two.js' ]    
};

// config/production.js
module.exports = {
  jsFiles : [ 'js/combined.js' ]
};
```

If you are using Express with a rendering engine, you can pass the list of files to each template:

```
// assuming `app` is an Express app
var config = require('config');
app.locals.jsFiles = config.jsFiles;
```

You can also use these lists from your `Gruntfile.js`, although you need to `require` them (since you probably need to use both);

```
var development = require('config/development');
var production  = require('config/production');
...
```

Comment: I think he's looking for a way to, in addition to making it configurable, to actually combine / concat all his js files.